# Node send mail from debian server to user's email

Tags: node.js

I have a debian 8 server and i want to send email to users.I know could use nodemailer and how to use it.i finished my web site.
But i dont know -i can send with gmail?
Note:i dont use host,i use server.Ty so much everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a gmail account. Note that there is a limit on how many emails you can send a day for free gmail accounts.

```
function sendMail (email, subject, text) {
var einfo;
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'example@gmail.com',
    pass: 'example'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'example@gmail.com',
  to: email,
  subject: subject,
  text: text
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
})
   return('Email send');
  }
```